# How to pass a variable from an Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am having trouble to display the value of String description in the textView of OneFragment.
I am new to Android programming,any help will be appreciated.`

Here is MainActivity

```
package com.example.dell.myop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.example.dell.myop.R;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.example.dell.myop.fragments.OneFragment;

import com.example.dell.myop.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import com.example.dell.myop.fragments.TwoFragment;





public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    String description;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=hamirpur,india&appid=41352ca35dd1be72cc7d9f47351d1b41");



        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }




    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Today");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Tomorrow");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Day After");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

DownloadTask

```
package com.example.dell.myop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.dell.myop.fragments.OneFragment;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity;

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {





    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;


        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data!=-1){
                char current = (char)data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();


            }
            return  result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("weather");
            for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Pulling items from the array
                    String main = oneObject.getString("main");
                    String description = oneObject.getString("description");
                    Log.i("main",main);
                    Log.i("description",description);






                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Oops
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

And here is OneFragment

```
package com.example.dell.myop.fragments;

/**
 * Created by Dell on 13-09-2016.
 */
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.dell.myop.DownloadTask;
import com.example.dell.myop.MainActivity;
import com.example.dell.myop.R;

import com.example.dell.myop.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment{







    public OneFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(description);
        return view;
    }




}
```

Comment: Fragment has a setArguments() method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You add a function setDescription(String text) to the fragment.  In the activity, you get the fragment then call that function.  The function should set the textview.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value from an AsyncTask back to the Activity that started it, you can inject the Activity object into the Task and then call a method of the Activity object to pass back the result.

In your case, you could override the DownloadTask constructor to take the Activity as an argument. Then when the task completes, you could call a method, e.g. `activity.setDescription(description)` to supply the value to the Activity. The Activity would then change the UI of the fragment.

I'm also new to Android so forgive me if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this , to send from activity

```
 EditOption editOption = new EditOption();-- your fragment 
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("id", z);
            args.putString("title",title);
            args.putString("desc",des);
            editOption.setArguments(args);
```

in fragment

```
            String title = getArguments().getString("title");
            String des = getArguments().getString("desc");
            z=  getArguments().getInt("id");
```

edit code based in your case ,

hope this help

Comment: How do I send the Data after the AsyncTask Finishes?